# [TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'DirectSms.sendDirectSms')]

Tags: javascript, react-native, typeerror

I am trying to send sms through my app using the NativeModules in my react native project. But I am getting this error:
`[TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'DirectSms.sendDirectSms')]`
Here is my code for send SMS:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

// import all the components we are going to use
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
  NativeModules,
  PermissionsAndroid,
} from 'react-native';

var DirectSms = NativeModules.DirectSms;

const App = () => {
  // Setting up States
  const [mobileNumber, setMobileNumber] = useState('');
  const [bodySMS, setBodySMS] = useState('');

  // async function to call the Java native method
  const sendDirectSms = async () => {
    if (mobileNumber != null) {
      try {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
          PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.SEND_SMS,
          {
            title: 'Send SMS App Sms Permission',
            message:
              'Send SMS App needs access to your inbox ' +
              'so you can send messages in background.',
            buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
            buttonPositive: 'OK',
          },
        );
        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
          DirectSms.sendDirectSms(mobileNumber, bodySMS);
          alert('SMS sent');
        } else {
          alert('SMS permission denied');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.warn(error);
        alert(error);
      }
    } else{
      alert("Mobile number is empty")
    }
  }
```

Can anybody tell me why it is showing null. I am using the SmsManager library of android and trying to create the react native bridge.

Comment: what is the value of `bodySMS`?

Comment: We enter it using TextInput

Comment: Are you sure it is correctly bound and has a value different from `null` when you call `DirectSms.sendDirectSms()`? Set a breakpoint at that position and inspect the value

Comment: Yep it is correctly bound.